# Always fails when use the regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to limit emails to those coming from my company only. This is what I have but it always fails:

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[RegularExpression(@"/\w+@mycompany\.com/", ErrorMessage = "You must use your mycompany email to register")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

This email always returns an error: `cooper@mycompany.com`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@"\w+@mycompany\.com"` remove the `/`

Comment: Prolly want anchors as well

Comment: The forward slashes are used in other languages to delimit the regex string, i.e instead of a single or double quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# regex, unlike PHP, JavaScript, and some other languages, you do not have to use delimiters.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+@mycompany\.com", ErrorMessage = "You must use your mycompany email to register")]
```

The regex is anchored in a `RegularExpressionAttribute` and it will match a string that

- `\w+` - Starts with alphanumeric, 1 or more occurrences
- `@` - then has a literal `@`
- `mycompany\.com` - and ends with a literal `mycompany.com` (dot must be escaped to match a literal dot).